# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, build-error

i trying to build my android app but (i think) after add firebase to the project its cant build correctly.

i receive this 4 errors:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

I try to disable some check box in the "Publish settings". After disable all check boxes its build correctly, without errors! BUUUUT in the app (on android) firebase doesnt work((( Its like "no internet connection" you khow. If i try to register account doesnt happend. Nothing

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

With Unity, [this works different](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#available-libraries) and that URL is indeed HTTP 404.
See [Download Google packages for Unity - Firebase App (Core)](https://developers.google.com/unity/archive#firebase_app_core).

The `.tar.gz` actually contains the Maven repository you're looking for.
This means, these packages could as well be served from `mavenLocal()`.
I'd suggest to grab the whole SDK from [firebase/firebase-unity-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/releases).

The dependencies are defined like this: [`GoogleDependencyFirebaseApp.xml`](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/main/ProjectSettings/GoogleDependencyFirebaseApp.xml).

Comment: how to fix my problem?